# How to deal with mongoose nested population?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make some nested population. User model is populated the way i expect it to be.

But i am having trouble with nested population of a Post model. It's not populated at all.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB`);

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:String,
    post: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Post'
    }
});
var PostSchema =  new Schema({
    title:String,
    subscriber:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Subscriber'
    }
});

var SubscriberSchema = new Schema({
    name:String
});

var User =  mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
var Post = mongoose.model('Post',PostSchema);
var Subscriber = mongoose.model('Subscriber',SubscriberSchema);

User
    .find()
    .populate([{
        path:'post',
        model:'Post',
        populate:{
            model:'Subscriber',
            path:'subscriber'
        }
    }])
    .exec()
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        mongoose.disconnect();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling .populate incorrectly.
Please try this:

```js
User
 .find()
 .populate('post')
 .populate({
  path: 'post',
  populate: {
   path: 'subscriber',
   model: 'Subscriber'
  }
 })
 .exec()
 .then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  mongoose.disconnect();
 });
```

For more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34444982/7006062) out.

Comment: I makes no difference. 'subscriber' field is still not populated

Comment: @user2397623 which Node.js and mongoose versions are you using?

Comment: @user2397623 I'm at mongoose 4.8.3 and node 6 and 7. It works. Here are the sources: http://jsbin.com/geyinabumi/1/edit?js Please make sure that you have data that is properly linked (I mean that _ids match)