# how to populate nested array ref? mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I found this post which is quite close to my need but somehow I still can't get it to work though

[Populate nested array in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222520/populate-nested-array-in-mongoose)

It's a bit hard to explain what kind of nested ref I am talking about.  I just start with the code

I have a Products Schema

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema(Object.assign({
    name: {type: String};
});
```

an order schema

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema(Object.assign({
    products: [ {
        product: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Products' },
        amount: { type: Number },
        total: { type: Number },
    } ],
});
```

I tried doing

```
    const order = await Orders.findOne({
        _id: 'orderId39843984203'
    }).populate({
        path: 'products',
        populate: {
            path: 'product'
        }
    });
```

I tried something like that, and few other ways such as `path: products.product`  or `path: products.product._id` and something simliar

but all I can get is the `_id`, it doesn't populate the whole thing.

Can someone please give me a hand or advice how this would work?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: this is how the document looks like in db for orderSchema

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ba2e2af52f2ff3f4226015c"
    },
    "products": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ba2e2ac52f22f3f4226015e"
            },
            "amount": 4,
            "total": 2940
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ba2e2ac52f2ff3f5226015d"
            },
            "amount": 1,
            "total": 840
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2018-09-19T23:58:36.339Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2018-09-19T23:58:36.505Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.populate({ path: 'nested', populate: { path: 'deepNested' }});
```

where `nested` is first level ref and `deepnested` is ref of first level of ref.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with this:

```
const order = await Orders.findOne({
    _id: 'orderId39843984203'
}).populate('products.product')
.exec((error, doc) => doc);
```

As per the [docs for populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: still no luck, I believe I also tried that before but anyways I tried it again but ya, no luck

Comment: I edited my post, showing how does the document looks like.  Donno why I do feel something is off