# Mongodb nested populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have 3 collections in MongoDB with the following Schema:

```
 const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    surname: {
     type: String
    }
})
userSchema.virtual('products', {
    ref: 'product',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'user'
})

userSchema.virtual('carts', {
    ref: 'cart',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'user'
})
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)

-----------

const Product = mongoose.model('product', {
    title: {
       type: String,
       required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        default: -1
    },

    user: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'user',
       required: true
    }
 })

--------

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    session_id: {
        type: String
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number
    },
    total: {
        type: Number
    },
    product: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product',
        required: true
    }
})

const CartSchema = new Schema({
    items: [ItemSchema],
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
        required: true
    },
    total_price: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
})
const Cart = mongoose.model('cart', CartSchema)
```

So let's say we have some data in these collections and I want to get the cart data of some user like this:

```
user = await User.findById(user_id).populate({
        path: 'carts',
        populate: {
            path: 'products',
            model: 'product'
        }
    })
return user.carts
```

I get the following response without giving me the product detail:

```
[
    {
        "total_price": 10,
        "_id": "5ff373073b92a40898c50508",
        "items": [
            {
                "_id": "5ff4d3b86404131811e392ef",
                "product": "5fe9ea426c3ff17b383dd599",
                "quantity": 5,
                "price": 2,
                "total": 10,
                "createdAt": "2021-01-05T21:01:44.269Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-01-05T21:01:44.269Z"
            }
        ],
        "user": "5fe255a5543b7420c9c29c8b",
    }
 ]
```

How its possible to get the product detail also, and am I right with structure of the collections? Thanks

Comment: What's the schema of the user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Populate nested array in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222520/populate-nested-array-in-mongoose)

Comment: @Aviv? Its written there as userSchema

Comment: My bad. DIdn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 const userSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    surname: {
     type: String
    },
    product: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product',
    },
    cart: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'cart',
    })
```

For what you are trying to achieve, virtuals should not be necessary.

> In Mongoose, a virtual is a property that is not stored in MongoDB.
> Virtuals are typically used for computed properties on documents.

Everything you need is stored in the DB and you are not computing anything.