# How to populate the ObjectId inside an array?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
  {
    orders: {
      userID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
      order: [
        {
          productID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Inventory' },
          quantity: { type: Number },
          vendorCoupon: { type: String },
        },
      ],
     }
  }
```

I have an orderSchema something like this. I can populate userID like that :

```
Order.find({ userID: req.body.userID }).populate('userID') 
 ... some other code snippet ...
```

But how should I populate the productID inside this order array ? I have to map all the productID's in the array. How can I implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Order.find({ userID: req.body.userID }).populate('userID').populate({
  path: 'order.productID'
});
```

> See also: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate & [Populate nested array in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222520/populate-nested-array-in-mongoose)